# I'm having trouble accessing the permissions section for private YouTube videos for automation

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to create an application that provides YouTube videos only to users registered in the application. To achieve this, I wanted to make the videos private and grant access to them through the YouTube API. However, I encountered some obstacles related to OAuth 2.0. I'm struggling to find a way to keep my application constantly authorized without human intervention. Is it possible to do this, and if so, how can I achieve it?

I attempted to use the API key, but it did not grant me access to the endpoints required to manage access to private videos. OAuth 2.0, which allows for such access, requires human intervention.

Comment: this use case is out of scope for the api